# How to diable previous dates in angular-io-datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-ui-datepicker

I dont know much about the angular 4, can any tell me how to diable previous dates in angular-io-datepicker.

Comment: You can use datepicker of primeng? it's better

Answer (score 0):

*************I apologize, this is not the correct datepicker pluggin.  But im leaving it just in case you want to switch

If this is the ui that you are using, check out the min date button.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fdatepicker

html:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
```

angularjs:

```
$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.options.minDate = $scope.options.minDate ? null : new Date();
  };
```

Comment: Sorry, I submitted it and then realized I was talking about the wrong datepicker

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `min` input to be able to do this.
Simply add it on the `input` tag where you placed the `mdDatepicker` directive, then bind `min` to the date that separates the valid dates from the invalid ones.
In this example I used `new Date()` to be able to disable all the dates that are prior to the current date.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<input [mdDatepicker]="datePicker" [min]="minDate">
             <button [mdDatepickerToggle]="datePicker"></button>
             <md-datepicker #datePicker></md-datepicker>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  minDate = new Date();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using the [datePicker of material2](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview).
I took a look at the API reference and the source code of the component you're using. I couldn't find a way to do what you wanted.